# ClinkOnce or register application URI?

Tags: windows, clickonce, url-scheme

We have a Windows application that must be started from a website. In this case, the user enters his username and password in the website, the website will do the authentication and must start the application with a JWT (which is received after authentication).

I see several applications that do the same. The first time a user "clicks" the URL an application is downloaded and installed on the local machine and all following times the application is just started after clicking the URL.

Now my question is what is nowadays the best (future proof) way to do this?

As far as I know, there are two ways to do this:

1. Create a ClickOnce application. This is already a very old technique, is this still valid and supported in Windows?
2. Register an application to a custom URI scheme. I think that in this case you must first install an application and therefore the user must perform two separate actions (I want the URL to only install if the application is not installed and otherwise immediately start the application).

Comment: Hey @Laurens, have you decided on a approach? I'd like to do the same. I tried a combination of starting a clickonce application using url protocol registry, but the clickonce setup doesn't support adding registry keys. Anyway, would love to hear your solution to the problem.

Comment: Hi @Gonzalioz, we decided to go with option 2, because the technology used for option 1 is obsolete.